# Can you get class comment programmatically

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible (is there a neat way) to get the class comment using reflection? I could read the .java file and get the comment but it's possible there might not be one so if I look for the first instance of /** and then */ I could end up with a method comment.

Please could you avoid code solutions as I want to crack this myself.

Comment: What is your exact goal? The comments are not part of generated code, so it is not available at runtime. You might want to see if Javadoc doclets can help you in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment is not retained in the class file, you have to go back to the original source to get comments.

If there is information you need at runtime, it should be stored in an annotation(s)  This can be accessible at runtime.

Comment: see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html and as an example of software using annotations see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/metadata.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Comments are stripped from your compiled code.

Comment: Or put another way, Comments are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: what if i have access to the .java file

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't think they're truly ignored by the compiler since they're accessible during annotation processing, but they're just not used to output actual code.

Comment: @G_H, I thought the annotation processor only processed annotations. I assume you mean it can process annotations in javadocs for example?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Normally it's only gonna see classes that contain an annotation to be processed, but you can use the wildcard `*` to see all compilation units. It allows you to inspect the source code structures through the javax.lang.model API. There's a way to see JavaDoc on elements by using `javax.lang.model.util.Elements.getDocComment`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware of, there's no way of doing this via reflection. I doubt commentary/JavaDoc is carried over to the actual class file after compilation. One way to do this would be the use of an annotation processor. Annotation processing doesn't use reflection, but rather the compile-time equivalent of source models/mirrors. It does allow you to get the documentation of a program element, like a class declaration or method. You could carry this over in a metadata file for use at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot get comments by reflection because compiler cut off comment, so they are not in .class.
By example, Eclipse gives you javadoc help only if you tell it where sources laid.

Answer (score 2):

If you really really want to do that, you can write an (external) application that parses your source file, and extract the comments. Then, with [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), you could take only the comments you're interested in (for example, the ones just above the keyword "class", or anything you want.

But if you don't mind me asking, why would you want to do that? If you really need to access that information, that means you need to promote it to something else than comments. Like some String constants somewhere in the application, or annotations on your class/methods, so that it's retained by the compiler and can be accessed using normal methods.

Answer (score 0):

Except for things already mentioned by others, reading from a source .java file is **not** reflection. Reflection operates on compiled code, .class files.